# Probelm with using Threads in Linux kernel Module

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am developing Linux kernel module which is communicating with my user-space C application. In this module, I am creating a thread. this is my module where I am facing the problem :

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <asm/siginfo.h>    //siginfo
#include <linux/rcupdate.h>    //rcu_read_lock
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>    //find_task_by_pid_type
#include <linux/debugfs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/fs.h> 
#include <linux/random.h> 
#include <linux/kthread.h> 

#define SIG_TEST 44    // we choose 44 as our signal number (real-time signals are in the range of 33 to 64)
#define BTN_FILE_PATH "/dev/input/event0"


char *str = BTN_FILE_PATH;
int file;

struct file *f;   // keyboard driver

// prototypage des fonctions read_in_thread & read_pid
int read_in_thread(void *data);
static ssize_t read_pid(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset);


static ssize_t write_pid(struct file *pfile, const char __user *buffer,
                                size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
   return 0;
}



struct read_args {
    struct file *pfile;
    const char __user *buffer;
    size_t length;
    loff_t *offset;
};


static ssize_t read_pid(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
  // création de la structure des arguments
    struct read_args args ;
    args.pfile = pfile;
    args.buffer = buffer;
    args.length = length;
    args.offset = offset;

struct task_struct *thread1;
char our_thread[20];
unsigned int rand;

get_random_bytes(&rand, sizeof(rand));
rand = rand % 250;
sprintf(our_thread, "thread%u", rand);

if(thread1==NULL)
{
thread1 = kthread_create(read_in_thread,&args,our_thread);
    if((thread1))
        {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Thread is created\n");
        printk("thread name %s\n", our_thread);
// lancement du thread
            wake_up_process(thread1);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Thread is awake\n");
        }
}

else 
printk("\nTHREAD1 IS NOT NULL!!! CAN NOT CREATE THREAD!!!\n"); 

return 0;                   
}



int read_in_thread(void *data) {

/************************** récupération des arguments *******************/

    struct read_args *const args = data;

/***************************   corps de la fonction ***********************/


// init des variables 

    char mybuf[10];
    enum { MAX_BUF_SIZE = 4096 };
    size_t buf_size = 0;
    char *buf = NULL;
    ssize_t total = 0;
    ssize_t rc = 0;
    struct task_struct *t;
    struct input_event ev[64];
    int yalv;

    int ret;
    struct siginfo info;
    int pid =0; 
    size_t amount = sizeof(ev);    


// récupération de l'ID du processus appelant

/* read the value from user space */
    if(args->length > 10)
        return -EINVAL;
    copy_from_user(mybuf, args->buffer, args->length);
    sscanf(mybuf, "%d", &pid);
    printk("pid = %d\n", pid);

    // the signal 
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(struct siginfo));
    info.si_signo = SIG_TEST;
    info.si_code = SI_QUEUE;    // this is bit of a trickery: SI_QUEUE is normally used by sigqueue from user space,
                    // and kernel space should use SI_KERNEL. But if SI_KERNEL is used the real_time data 
                    // is not delivered to the user space signal handler function. 
    info.si_int = 260;          //real time signals may have 32 bits of data.

    rcu_read_lock();
    t = pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID);  //find the task_struct associated with this pid
    if(t == NULL){
        printk("no such pid\n");
        rcu_read_unlock();
        return -ENODEV;
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();


// lecture blocquante

    rc = kernel_read(f, ev, amount, &f->f_pos);

// récupération de l'événement

    if (rc > 0) {
            for (yalv = 0; yalv < (int) (rc / sizeof(struct input_event)); yalv++) {
            if (ev[yalv].type == EV_KEY) {
                if (ev[yalv].value == 0)
                     //eval_keycode(ev[yalv].code);
                     info.si_int = ev[yalv].code;  

// envoie du signal vers le processus appelant avec les événements lu

                                         ret = send_sig_info(SIG_TEST, &info, t);    //send the signal
                         printk("signal was send\n");
                     if (ret < 0) {
                            printk("error sending signal\n");
                        kfree(buf);
                            return ret;
                         }              
            }
        }

                if (rc < amount) {
                    /* Didn't read the full amount, so terminate early. */
                    rc = 0;
                }

    } 

    /* Free temporary buffer. */
        kfree(buf);

return 0;
}




static const struct file_operations my_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .write = write_pid,
    .read = read_pid,
    //.open = open_pid,
};



static int __init signalexample_module_init(void)
{
     printk(KERN_INFO "Initializing LKM");
    /* we need to know the pid of the user space process
      * -> we use debugfs for this. As soon as a pid is written to 
      * this file, a signal is sent to that pid
      */
    /* only root can write to this file (no read) */
    register_chrdev(240, "mod", &my_fops);
    file = debugfs_create_file("signalconfpid", 0200, NULL, NULL, &my_fops);
    f = filp_open(str, O_RDONLY , 0);
    //printk("%d",f);

    return 0;
}



static void __exit signalexample_module_exit(void)
{
    unregister_chrdev(240, "mod");
    debugfs_remove(file);

}

module_init(signalexample_module_init);
module_exit(signalexample_module_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

When I execute my user-space program for the first time, everything is working well and it prints for me on the console :

```
Thread is created 
thread name thread91
Thread is awake
```

But when I try to execute it again, it prints :

```
THREAD1 IS NOT NULL!!! CAN NOT CREATE THREAD!!!
```

I think that the probelm is in **task_struct *thread1** which still holding information about the first thread which was created in my first execution of the program.

Could anyone help me how to solve the problem ? How can I edit my code in order to make it run much more times correctly ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentionned, the thread is correctly marked as not null since it is *already* running. So the behaviour is intended.

So in order to solve your issue you have to describe what is you actual intended behavior.

If you want to make it run multiple times, you might want to use a local variable to run the thread (for instance storing it in an array for later communication).

You could also wait the previous thread to complete before running the next one.

Comment: Using local variable So I need to define `static struct task_struct *thread1` inside the `read_pid` function ? And how can I wait the thread to complete ?

Comment: Yes. A way to do that is to use kthread_stop [defined there](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/kthread.c#L547).

Comment: The first solution is not working, I am facing same trouble with it.

Comment: It should work. Please edit your post with your current code so that we can understand your issue

Comment: Although static, thread1 is still global in the code you posted! Please, verify your code before saying it doesn't work, the modifications I asked for are straightforward

Comment: I published my first code in the edited version. It does not include the modifications that you have suggested

Comment: I have declared `struct task_struct *thread1` inside `read_pid` function as you have mentioned, the problem was that it had type `static` as you said. Now it does not print to me `THREAD1 IS NOT NULL!!! CAN NOT CREATE THREAD!!!` But it says `pid = 0` `No such pid` and this when I try to re-excute my user-space program. I edited my code and I included the first solution

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel code lives before and after your user space code started and finished to run. So when you execute your command for the first time, the kernel thread is created, as it is the first time the `read_pid` called so the thread is created. But after the `read_pid` done, the kernel did not stop. So the thread is still there. It looks like you should create your thread in the driver's `probe` function, and write the threads logic in the way that it only prepares data for the `read_pid` call. The signal usage looks absolutely unnecessary in your case.

Comment: you said " But after the read_pid done, the kernel did not stop. So the thread is still there. " I think that the best solution is to stop it after `read_pid` function is done. Isn't it ?

Comment: This is not how kernel designed to work. You don't start and kill threads any time the user wants from your driver something. If it is something you can provide synchronously, don't create a thread, just send it from the `read` function. If it is something that takes a lot of time to process, then make a thread which processes the data and prepares it continuously, and return the result to user only when he ask from the `read` function